# Chaos in chemical reactions

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, theoretical-chemistry

I recently read about Chaos Theory and was wondering if a chemical reaction results in or shows characteristics of chaos (I found a few examples of such reactions [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_famous_chemical_reactions_yielding_chaos/amp))

> Chaos theory concerns deterministic systems whose behavior can in principle be predicted. Chaotic systems are predictable for a while and then 'appear' to become random.

If the reaction becomes unpredictable towards the time of attainment of equilibrium we can't possibly determine how the reaction will proceed during the time frame so **will the reaction attain a state of equilibrium** and will it be at the time it should've without chaos being in the picture?

**If the equilibrium shifts can we quantify by how much and how much more or less time will it take to attain it in general or we need to take specific reactions and analyze them?**

**Also after attaining equilibrium can the system again show Chaotic behaviour and if it does what can se say about the state of equilibrium?**

Comment: Indeed, there is quite a bit of chaos in chemical reactions. I wonder, though, what's the point of your question.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I was curious about chaos in Chemical Reactions and the concept of equilibrium which pretty much says that we can predict the future and determine the concentration of different reagents involved and hence I'm asking this

Comment: Well, can you tell someone what they'll do 20 years in the future? Can you tell if someone will die at all? Reaction like life is unpredictable, but inevitably ends.

Comment: @Mithoron it does and will as a system stays in chaos only for specific time intervals but I'm asking is will the reaction attain equilibrium at the same time as it was supposed to and will it stay in the dynamic equilibrium or move away from it

Comment: I still don't get your point... When you die, you stay dead, people might somewhat postpone death, though.

Comment: @Mithoron your analogy isn't helping. I am simply asking whether the reaction will attain equilibrium at the time when it would've if there was no chaos or not? It's a binary question also if it doesn't then why and how can we find out the deviation at the point of time equilibrium and also when it does will it ever re-enter a chaotic state and when it does will the equilibrium shift?
Sorry if my previous (deleted) comment was not friendly it was a mistake keeping the caps lock on

Comment: My comment did answer that: chaotic regime does somewhat alter time of completion of reaction and when it's complete, it's complete.

Comment: [An Introduction to Nonlinear Chemical Dynamics: Oscillations, Waves, Patterns, and Chaos](https://books.google.com/books?id=rE0SDAAAQBAJ).

Comment: @Mithoron and can we quantity by how much it deviates?  and also provide the sources for your claims

Comment: What Mithoron says is based on chemical common sense. The very basics of thermodynamics and kinetics. If you want to quantify anything, you should be a lot more specific about the system.

Comment: @Karl I want to know the general way in which these things are quantified I don't have any specific example or reaction in mind

Comment: I think the point of chaotic (nonlinear) behavior is precisely that prediction becomes difficult and not amenable to standard linear methods. However you can probably bracket the expected response such as the time to equilibrium (provided the system is not continuously driven), as well as say something about the duration of intervals during which the system may behave "chaotically". You may want to consult a physics or math source for more details, or read more about the individual reactions you cite.

Comment: @BuckThorn I've updated the question making it more clear to understand hopefully

Comment: Equillibrium does not shift, unless you actively change the composition or the temperature or pressure. Never. You should revise your highschool natural science.

Comment: @Karl I got your point I thought maybe chaos can shift it as Le Chatelier's Principle did not account for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A homogeneous reaction mixture can hardly show macroscopical chaotic behaviour. [Well known cyclic counterexamples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction) exist, and practically any reaction which proceeds faster than diffusion or mechanical mixing can homogenise it again (e.g. any reaction that generates a lot of heat!) is liable to show some intermediate chaotic concentration gradients. Its usually hard to notice, and most reactions are perfectly reproducible, if you set them up in the same way (*educt impurities!*).

If your reaction vessel contains inflows of different chemical composition, then you easily get chaotic behaviour. Think about a tube reactor. I believe chemical engineers are spending a lot of their time trying to control and avoid chaos.

Comment: Thanks for the info but this doesn't exactly answer my question

Comment: @StackUpPhysics Then I also do not understand your question.

Comment: you have given a qualitative analysis however you didn't answer the things like how much more time will it take to attain equilibrium and will the system oppose this equilibrium if chaos kicks in again or not

Comment: Just FYI I am not the downvoter

Comment: no I'm asking that after equilibrium can it again become chaotic

Comment: @StackUpPhysics Are you seriously asking wether a system can stay chaotic when it has reached thermodynamic equillibrium? And of course a chaotic system will take a different amount of time to reach equillibrium than a reaction that just progresses straigthforward. It is a different system, after all!

Comment: One hint, perhaps that is behind your misunderstanding: Chaos is *by no means* a state of maximal entropy. Chaotic systems usually show selfsimilarity! Thermodynamic equillibrium IS the point of maximal entropy, and there is no way out of it.

Comment: yes I'm asking the first question you mention I think it can but I'm not sure as this isn't my area of expertise

Comment: Why do you think it is called *equillibrium*? When have you ever seen that something that was in motion and has come to rest suddenly starts rolling uphill again?

Comment: it is in a dynamic equilibrium hence I thought maybe chaos could disturb the equilibrium as it's impossible to predict how the processes proceed during that time frame

Comment: @StackUpPhysics In a dynamic equillibrium, any local excess concentration that occurs must favour the reaction that makes it vanish again. Le Chateliers principle. Otherwise you had a perpetuum mobile. Chaos depends on self–amplification. Heat production speeds up the further reaction, self–catalysis only occurs when the catalyst concentration is still very low, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What I think: A macroscopic chaotic system is a system whose "components" influence each other, and the macroscopic outcome depends on the status of the components. This happens for the two-arms pendulum, for air particles in cigarette smoke, and for particles in wind. Each microscopic variation can be propagated between particles, and the final status of the system can vary a lot, as varies the status of the particles (eg: temperature, position).

Typical chemical reactions, at the typical macroscopic level have different features: they show "average" properties of the microscopic systems of which they are made (that's the base of statistical thermodynamics, and of Boltzmann's law).

Anyway, if we look closer, we might find chaos, after all: fluctuations of thermodynamic properties arise from the microscopic cause of macroscopic properties (for example, if the temperature of a liquid was mesured with extreme precision every picosecond, it would show variations arising from the way the particles hit the sensor). The variations arise from complex interactions between the microscopic components, and they are non-predictable. That is chaos, albeit not as "macroscopic" as the behavior of cigarette smoke or of the double pendulum.

Comment: Chaos means that you have variations at least on a mesoscopic lenghtscale, and it absolutely needs an energy source, unless you have a completely lossless system. Its *not* to be confused with high entropy. The surface shape of a cloud is highly structured, selfsimilar and chaotic, fog (or the inside of the cloud) isn't. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction#/media/File:The_Belousov-Zhabotinsky_Reaction.gif